# 2021 Potential Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

It's time for us all to consider holding an election for a new volunteer moderators on Bioinformatics.

Three moderators were appointed when this site was created back in 2017. Since then most of them have resigned, meaning we're due for some fresh moderators. The basic job doesn't entail terribly much work, mostly going through the queue of flagged issues once or twice a day and handling them. Potential moderators could ideally also go through new posts and help handle issues there before they get flagged.

In the end, it's not a lot of work to being a moderator, and this is a relatively small SE site.

You can also take a look at [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)? and the [Theory of moderation (revisited)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/?_ga=2.162496764.1584694404.1614677392-1645080366.1585295816) to get a bit of a feeling as to what being a moderator actually entails.

**Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.**

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.

Answer (score 6):

I'm interested in this. I run through my review queues once a day on average anyway, and I'm a moderator on biostars. If the duties are similar on this site as well, I'd do a similar job here.

Comment: I think you would be great!

Comment: Thank you, @KamilSJaron

Answer (score 3):

I might also run. I haven't quite made up my mind yet, but as an ex mod, I can confirm what Devon said: the workload of moderating this site is very low and doesn't require a lot of your time.

I guess I'll decide for sure if and when we have an election, but yes, I am thinking I might run.

---

In case anyone cares, I decided not to run in the end because we had a fine crop of candidates, all of whom I am happy to vote for and I'd rather bring in some new blood!

Comment: I thought you already were a mod!

Comment: @RamRS I was, but then I stepped down due to various things that caused me to want to limit my connection to SE. I now feel a little better about SE and the direction they are going in, at least I've seen signs that they're honestly trying to improve on the things that bother me so I am more willing to be a mod on a second site.

Comment: Did you resign to get elected twice?! ^^

Comment: @KamilSJaron well, I need to get my validation from _somewhere_, right? :P More seriously, I was very, very disappointed in Stack Overflow Inc. and how they behaved and [didn't feel up to moderating more than one site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18894/85695). It somehow felt like too much of an endorsement of the company. I kept my first mod post since that was in the first community I really got deeply involved with, but resigned my other two. I now feel much better towards the company, they've taken some important steps for me, so I felt OK with coming back to mod here again.

Comment: Damn, I completely forgot about that affair (and I did not know that's why you stepped down). What were the nicer things SE did after that? Anyway, I just filled my self-nomination, so it's on!

Comment: You did? Great! We need good candidates! As for what they did better, there's a [new person](https://stackoverflow.com/company/leadership/teresa-dietrich) at the helm and since she joined, there has been a marked change in how the company interacts with the community. Both publicly in Meta and with the various moderators across the network. Enough so to make me much more enthusiastic about participating again.

Comment: That sounds great, then I am looking forward to see your candidacy :-)

Comment: I think you probably won't be seeing my candidacy. I am more than happy with all three of the candidates who have stepped forward so far, so I think I'll leave you all to it! We have three fine candidates already.